# Syntax of process substitution

Tags: shell-script, process-substitution

I am really having some trouble understanding pipeline substitution. I have a program that I run with the make command that writes to stdout. What I want to be able to do is parse through the output based on criteria to multiple files.

The command I have in my script is as follows:

```
make | tee > (grep @@@ >> ooo_output.txt) > (grep cycles >> ooo_cpi.txt)
```

This seems to follow the same format that can be found in this wiki page http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution, however, when I run my script I get the following error:

```
./test_script: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test_script: line 15: `   make | tee > (grep @@@ >> ooo_output.txt)'
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? Thanks =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write `>( )` not `> ( )` to get it to work properly :)

Comment: Still getting used to the spacing in bash scripts. Thank you!